# Best approach for validating anti forgery token?

Tags: security, standards, owasp, websecurity

Where should I put anti-forgery token in the request? (as per the latest standards)

- Header
- Form Body

Comment: Are you asking either of Header or Form Body which is better or which one to use for a specific type of application.

Comment: simply which is better Header or Form Body?